# firebug console.table returning undefined

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am trying to view the contents of a 2 dimensional array. I found out about using `console.table()` [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/utilities/firebug-console-tips/). Every time I call `console.log` in the console I get `undefined`. I have tried running the site's example code

```
var table1 = new Array(5);
for (var i=0; i<table1.length; i++)
    table1[i] = [i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5, i+6, i+7];
console.table(table1);
```

as well as calling `console.table` on my own arrays while paused in the debugger.

Any thoughts on how I can get this to work?

Edit: `undefined` is also returned when I just type `console.log("abc");` in the console.

Edit2: reinstalling firebug seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Dumb question, but you **are** using Firebug, right? This isn't a Developer Tools feature, so it won't work in Chrome/IE. It works fine for me in my FireFox Firebug

Comment: Yeah I'm using Firebug. I just installed it today since it seemed like it would work better for visualizing these arrays.

Comment: Your code is working and console.log is working too (for me)

Comment: @Jias Yeah it's definitely a nice tool for that. Everything works fine for me though. So if you open your browser, go to Firebug's console, and just type in `console.log("abc");`, it shows `undefined`?

Comment: Sounds like you have something hijacking `console.log()`. If you type `console.log.toString()` into the console, what do you get?

Comment: @Ian yes. I've restarted the browser a couple of times and still had the same issue. I will try reinstalling firebug to see if that fixes it.

Comment: If this issue reoccurs and you have some steps to reproduce it, you should [report it to the Firebug Working Group](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry), so it can be fixed.

Comment: I have same issue(on firefox) it was working fine but just got broken or some thing I tried `console.log.toString()`
it shows following
`"function log() {
    [native code]
}"`

Comment: Any fix for this issue?, I am having the same when I typed console.log.toString()

Comment: @Manza any reason why you're using Firebug? Development for it has been stopped since Firefox DevTools is robust enough and accomplishes what Firebug set out to do. As I said in the edit resinstalling Firebug fixed the issue.

Comment: @Jias I have reinstall firebug, and didnt fixed the issue, I even uninstall and reinstall firefox and then install firebug and I still have same issue. I really like using firebug, as it allows me to write big chunks of JS directly before i actually write it on page and then refresh the page, I think it is faster, I havent been able to find it in tools the same option, or is there a way?